# Prove that $A\cap\overline{(\bar B\cap C)}\subset B\cup(A\cap \bar C)$, with equality iff $B\cap\bar A=\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A\cap\overline{(\bar B\cap C)}\subset B\cup(A\cap \bar C)$, and that equality holds if and only if $B\cap\bar A=\varnothing$

Where $\bar X$ denotes the complement of $X$.

Question**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjcT0.png)**

I have some idea how to prove if B intersect with the complement of A is empty, then the statement is true. But I have no idea how to prove the other direction. I have tried to assume to the contrary that B intersect with A is not empty. However, I could not find a contradiction.

Comment: Your using the **wrong** strategy to attack the problem.  You only have 3 sets, $A,B,$ and $C$, so there are only 8 possible classifications for each element, re which of the 3 sets that it is in.  Simply set up a table that identifies all 8 possibilites and then compare the LHS and RHS of the conjecture.  An illustration of this approach is given by the following link, with the exception that the link refer to  statements rather than sets.  The approach is identical:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821921/negate-and-simplify-p-wedge-q-vee-r-wedge-neg-p-vee-neg-q-vee-r/3822222#3822222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use De Morgan's law, the double negation law, and the distributive law to get

$$A \cap \overline{\left(\overline{B} \cap C\right)} = A \cap \left(\overline{\overline{B}} \cup \overline{C}\right) = A \cap \left(B \cup \overline{C}\right) = \left(A \cap B \right) \cup \left(A \cap \overline{C}\right) \subset B \cup \left(A \cap \overline{C}\right)$$

because $A \cap B \subset B$. Now when does the equality hold? What can we say about $A$ and $B$ in this case?

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is a subset of RHS. If equality holds it would be a subset of LHS. But LHS $\subseteq A$, so we get $B \subseteq A$. This implies $B \cap \overline {A}=\emptyset$.