# Prove that $(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \implies (P \vee R) \leftrightarrow (Q \vee S).$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, problem-solving

Let $P, Q, R$ and $S$ be statements. Prove that

$$(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \implies (P \vee R) \leftrightarrow (Q \vee S).$$

**My attempt:**

I already check that this logical implication is true, by showing that the conditional statement $(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \to (P \vee R) \leftrightarrow (Q \vee S)$ is a tautology.

Although, I am trying to come up with a derivation of this implication. Here is what I have

$$(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \implies (P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P) \wedge (R \to S) \wedge (S \to R).$$

Using the *Material Implication*, I deduce that

$$(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P) \wedge (R \to S) \wedge (S \to R)  \implies (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P) \wedge (\neg R \vee S) \wedge (\neg S \vee R).$$

I thought that maybe I could use the *Distributive Law* to continue to simplifying this expression. By doing this, I had to rotate my sheet, because the expression was really big.

I can continue this until I got something, but the expression is becoming extremely length.

**Is there any hint of what I should do in order to prove this logical implication?**

**Or any simpler idea of what to do?**

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: [Here's a proof that it's a tautology.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((P%20%E2%86%94%20Q)%20%E2%88%A7%20(R%20%E2%86%94%20S))%E2%86%92((P%20%E2%88%A8%20R)%20%E2%86%94(%20Q%20%E2%88%A8%20S%20)))

Comment: @Shaun is taht a proof by contradiction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "I already check ...".  Since there are only 4 statements, there are only $2^4$ = 16 possibilities, re each statement being true or false.  In my opinion, a truth table is therefore better than elegance.  See my (user2661923) answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821921/negate-and-simplify-p-wedge-q-vee-r-wedge-neg-p-vee-neg-q-vee-r,

Comment: Yes, @Andrew. ${}$

Comment: @Shaun that was really helpful, thank you so much for showing me that :)

Comment: You're welcome, @AirMike; I'm glad it helped!

Comment: @user2661923 I meant that I did the truth table and confirmed it that it is a tautology. Now I wan to take a step further and find a derivation for it, since by the *Completeness Theorem* [Godel], such derivation must exists

Comment: What type of derivation do you want? I can give a derivation using natural deduction rules, but I don't know if that is what you need.

Comment: @Maurocurto thank you for your attention! I am looking a derivation using some standard rules of inference (such as *Simplification*, *Modus Ponens*,...) and some equivalences as well such as the *Material Implication,* *De Morgan’s Law* and the like :)

Comment: @AirMike Good clarification.  Based on your response, I regard your *further step* as a **very positive approach**, which (unfortunately) I am unable to help you with.

Comment: @user2661923 it is okay, I really appreciate your attention! Thank you :)

Comment: No simple way using equivalences... The bi-conditional is a bad beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P, Q, R$ and $S$ be statements, and consider the following statement

$$(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \tag{1}$$

Using the rule of inference that states that for any statements $P$ and $Q$ $P \leftrightarrow Q \iff (P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P),$ we get the following

$$(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P) \wedge (R \to S) \wedge (S \to R) \tag{2}$$

Applying the *Material Implication* to each conditional statement in $(2)$ yields the following expression

$$(\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P) \wedge (\neg R \vee S) \wedge (\neg S \vee R) \tag{3}$$

Using the Rule of inference of *Simplification,* we get the following four disjunctions

$$\neg P \vee Q \tag{4}$$
$$\neg Q \vee P \tag{5}$$
$$\neg R \vee S \tag{6}$$
$$\neg S \vee R \tag{7}$$

Next, we apply the rule of *Addition* to each of the previous expressions. Namely, we will add $S$ to $(4),$ $R$ to $(5),$ $Q$ to $(6)$ and $P$ to $(7).$

$$\neg P \vee Q \vee S \tag{8}$$
$$\neg Q \vee P \vee R \tag{9}$$
$$\neg R \vee S \vee Q \tag{10}$$
$$\neg S \vee R \vee P \tag{11}$$

By *Adjunction,* we get the following expression

$$(\neg P \vee Q \vee S) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P \vee R) \wedge (\neg R \vee S \vee Q) \wedge (\neg S \vee R \vee P) \tag{12}$$

Using the *Distributive Law* yields that

$$\big( (\neg P \wedge \neg R) \vee (Q \vee S) \big) \wedge \big( (\neg Q \wedge \neg S) \vee (P \vee R) \big) \tag{13}$$

Which, by the *De Morgan’s Law*, is equivalent to

$$\big( \neg(P \vee R) \vee (Q \vee S) \big) \wedge \big( \neg(Q \vee S) \vee (P \vee R) \big) \tag{14}$$

Using, again, the *Material Implication* we write our previous expression as

$$\big( (P \vee R) \to (Q \vee S) \big) \wedge \big( (Q \vee S) \to (P \vee R)\big) \tag{15}$$

Finally, using the first rule of inference used here to deduce $(2)$ from $(1),$ we get

$$(P \vee R) \leftrightarrow (Q \vee S) \tag{16}$$

Hence, we have proved that $(1) \implies (16),$ i.e.

$$(P \leftrightarrow Q) \wedge (R \leftrightarrow S) \implies (P \vee R) \leftrightarrow (Q \vee S) \ \text{.  } \text{ } \text{ }\square$$

Comment: I returned now to this problem, and I think that this might work! What do you think, @BrianM.Scott ? :)