# How to prove $A \lor B \to ¬(¬A \land ¬B)$ without LNC

Tags: logic

How can I prove $A \lor B \to ¬(¬A \land ¬B)$ without using Law of Noncontradiction and De Morgan’s laws.

I know it looks very obvious. But I still can’t come up with a way to prove it from scratch.

Comment: Check that it is a tautology

Comment: kind of a cop out but proof by cases would show its true

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#A%E2%88%A8B%E2%86%92%C2%AC(%C2%ACA%E2%88%A7%C2%ACB)

Comment: Are you allowed to use a *truth table*, re https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821921/negate-and-simplify-p-wedge-q-vee-r-wedge-neg-p-vee-neg-q-vee-r/3822222#3822222

Comment: @Physor nice response.

Comment: What does "from scratch" mean? You say what you aren't allowed to use but what *are* you allowed to use?

Comment: I see I was a bit ambiguous. Yes a proof by tautology is allowed

Comment: @Physor, that is quite smart. Thank you

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. Any means is actually allowed. A proof without using a truth table would even be most interesting however

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Assume $(\lnot A \land \lnot B)$ and use $\land$-elim.

Then use $\lor$-elim with the premise to derive $\bot$ under both sub-cases.

Then, conclude by $\to$-intro.

Comment: I’m very new to logic. So I might be mistaken. But isn’t deriving $\bot$ using the law of non contradiction

Comment: It is a Proof by Contradiction (or an Indirect Proof of Negation).  When you can derive A contradiction under an assumption you may discharge the assumption to deduce its negation.$$\small\begin{array}{|l}~~~\begin{array}{|l}a\vee b\\\hline~~~\begin{array}{|l}\neg a\land\neg b\\\hline~~\vdots\\\bot\end{array}\\\neg(\neg a\land\neg b)\end{array}\\(a\lor b)\to\neg(\neg a\land\neg b)\end{array}$$The elipsed bit is a Proof by Cases (using rule of $\vee$ Elimination, as suggested).  Just make two subproofs and derive a contradiction in each case, @DavidOkogbenin .

Answer (score 0):

Let $C\equiv A \vee B$ and $D\equiv \lnot(\lnot A \wedge \lnot B)$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A& B & C & D &   C\to D \\ \hline
 1& 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
1 &  0 & 1 & 1 & \color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
0 & 1  & 1 & 1 & \color{blue}{1}\\ \hline
0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
\end{array}
where $1\equiv \text{true}$ and $0\equiv \text{false}$. Now we can see that $C\to D$ is *tautological proposition*.

Answer (score 0):

Under the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), or [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation), we may prove this by giving an appropriate function. $∨$ is interpreted as disjoint union, $∧$ as product, $→$ as the function type, and $¬ A$ as $A → ⊥$, where $⊥$ is an empty type. Proposition variables are just types held to be abstract. Here is an Agda proof:

```
lemma : A ⊎ B → ¬ (¬ A × ¬ B)
lemma (inj₁ a) (na , nb) = na a
lemma (inj₂ b) (na , nb) = nb b
```

This function corresponds to a proof in natural deduction. Defining a function taking arguments corresponds to → introduction; function application corresponds to → elimination/modus ponens; pattern matching on the sum/product corresponds to ∨/∧ elimination.