# How to proof "(∧)→¬(¬∨¬)" is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, natural-deduction

That is part of my homework and I really have no idea about that. Really need some help.

There is the question:

In our proof system for Sentential, if there is a proof of ℬ from  then →ℬ is a tautology. Use a proof to show that the following sentence is a tautology.
(∧)→¬(¬∨¬)

Comment: Can you use truth tables? Here you can find my answer for a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847620/798113.

Comment: It's just De Morgan's Law.

Comment: Sounds like you need to show $\{P\land Q\}\vdash\lnot(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)$, what rules your proof system have?

Comment: And also check the Syllabus of your course, just make sure your instructor allows you to ask answer or hint for homework questions online.

Comment: As per comment above, use truth table. But you have used the tag "natural-deduction": if so, do you know ND rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I took this yesterday in my discrete mathematics class. you could either use a truth table, or just use the double negation and distributive laws. Basically $\neg(\neg  \vee \neg )$ becomes $(\wedge)$ because $\neg(\neg P)= P$, $\neg (\neg Q)$ and negating the or operator makes it an and operator(because logic!). So the end result is $(\wedge )→(\wedge )$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about proving that something involving only a few number of independent statements is a tautology, is to make use of the truth table. The underlying principle which you are appealing to is the completeness theorem, which is well known.

So, start doing like this:

- Form a truth table, where you have one column for the truth values of $P$, and one column for the truth value of $Q$.
- Then find out what are the various truth values for the two things in question you get for various combinations of the truth values of $P$ and $Q$.
- Observe whether these two truth values always match or not. If they do then you have a tautology, and otherwise you don't.